# Broadcasting and Listening in C, best way?

Tags: c, broadcast

I have followed Beej's guide (http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#broadcast) to creating two C programs, one to broadcast, and one to listen.

What if I wanted to combine the two in one program which runs, constantly listens in the background and whatever the user types, it is broadcast to all the other broadcasters/listeners.

**Which is the best approach?**

Should I create two **threads** which will run simultaneously? One for listening and one for broadcasting?

OR

Should I use the **select()** method using file descriptors?

OR

Is there **another** way which I am not aware of?

I am not fully aware of how either one of them works so that is why I am asking which the best approach is so I can study one in depth.

Thank you!

Comment: Many options: poll, http://libevent.org/, http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html

Comment: Also check out: http://swtch.com/~rsc/thread/